# Filtering DataGridView without changing the datasource - null reference error

Tags: c#, datagridview, filtering

I want to implement a simple quick search / aka Filter on data that is already loaded into DataGridView without altering the datasource.

This is my simple UI:

[image]

This is how I tried to filter my data (based on answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10049875/2332336)):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<Line> myLines = new List<Line>()
        {
            new Line() { Sku = "VCF001", Qty = 1 },
            new Line() { Sku = "VCF002", Qty = 1 },
            new Line() { Sku = "VCF003", Qty = 1 },
        };
        dataGridView1.DataSource = myLines;
    }

    private void searchBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        (dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter 
            = string.Format("Sku LIKE '%{0}%'", searchBox.Text);
    }
}

public class Line
{
    public string Sku { get; set; }
    public int Qty { get; set; }
}
```

When I started to type "VC" I am getting this error:

> System.NullReferenceException was unhandled   Message=Object reference
>   not set to an instance of an object.

[image]

How the quick search / filtering should work is like this:

- If I type "VC" it should show all 3 rows
- IF I type "VCF001" it should only show row having that sku

Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    List<Line> myLines {get;set;}

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myLines = new List<Line>()
        {
            new Line() { Sku = "VCF001", Qty = 1 },
            new Line() { Sku = "VCF002", Qty = 1 },
            new Line() { Sku = "VCF003", Qty = 1 },
        };
        dataGridView1.DataSource = myLines;
    }

    private void searchBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.DataSource = myLines.Where(l => l.Sku.ToLower().Contains(searchBox.Text.ToLower())).ToList();

    }
}

public class Line
{
    public string Sku { get; set; }
    public int Qty { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This is `in a way` modifying the datasource. Can it not be made to work with the built in `RowFilter` feature on the DataGridView? The posted question is a cut down version of my actual code. In my real scenario, the datasource is a DataTable filled in by a db query, hence why I said I didn't want to modify the datasource (i.e. re-queue for each search)...

Comment: So you can try `DataGridView.Select` then. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333824/net-framework-datatable-selectstring-method-when-the-filter-expression-contai

Answer (score 0):

Try using something like this:

```
dv.RowFilter = "Sku Like '%" + searchBox.Text + "%'
```